# random factor structure for diversity surveys with repeat visits

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I’m involved in a project where we surveyed native insect communities across a large spatial gradient. Each site was surveyed twice over two summers for a total of 4 visits. We are hoping to analyze patterns in the abundance and richness of these communities across different land use types, regions, and management regimes. We are currently using both `glmmPQL`  and `lmer` depending on the distribution of each variable and are struggling to build an effective structure for our random effects.

Our data is currently structured such that each visit to a site is its own row, such that each site is listed multiple times.

We have two questions regarding how to structure our random effects.

- First, do we need to include both `SITE` and `VISIT` as random effects to address the repeated measures, or is it sufficient to just include `SITE`?
- Secondly, if we have 1 predictor variable that was measured only once per year and another that was measured twice per year, how would this change our random effect structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do we need to include both SITE and VISIT as random effects to address the repeated measures, or is it sufficient to just include SITE?

**tl;dr** use just `1|SITE` for linear mixed models; `1|SITE/VISIT` if you want to allow for overdispersion in GLMMs, otherwise `1|SITE`.

Typically one would include this as `1|SITE/VISIT` ("`VISIT` nested within `SITE`", equivalent to `1|SITE+SITE:VISIT` or "main effect of `SITE` plus the interaction between `1|SITE` and `1|VISIT`") in the model, but since you have only a single observation at each `VISIT` for each `SITE`, the `1|SITE:VISIT` term is an *observation-level* random effect. You definitely *don't* want to include it in your linear mixed models (i.e. `lmer`); if you include it in your generalized linear mixed models it will act as a model of overdispersion. If your data are not overdispersed (i.e. the conditional distribution of counts at a particular site has variance less than or equal to the mean), then you might not need the overdispersion term.

> Secondly, if we have 1 predictor variable that was measured only once per year and another that was measured twice per year, how would this change our random effect structure?

In general, you don't have to worry about the levels at which fixed-effect predictors get measured; this gets handled automatically. I assume you're going to do something like assuming that the once-measured variable is constant across the two visits within a year?

In general I would recommend `glmer` over `glmmPQL` unless you have a particular reason to use the latter.

Comment: We started using glmmPQL because we were getting convergence issues with glmer. We did try rescaling and adding in control code to specify number of iterations but the convergence warning still came up. @Ben Bolker do you have any suggestions for another way to deal with this? Thank you again for your help =D

Comment: did you look at `?convergence`? the gold standard is to try with another optimizer and see if you get the same results (coefficients, likelihood, etc.)